# JQuery: How to give a width of two other element's sum?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, overflow

I want my .scrollbox to be a width of two element's sum * a variable.

```
var videos = $('.videolink').length;
        $ (".scrollbox").width(
            $ ( (".ytimg").width()+(.videotext).width() )*videos
    })
```

Comment: Missing quotes in `$ ( (".ytimg").width()+(.videotext).width() )*videos`? try `(".videotext")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just need some code cleanups (attach "$" to "(", add "$" to the right places).

```
var videos = $('.videolink').length;
$(".scrollbox").width(
   ( $('.ytimg').width() + $('.videotext').width() ) * videos
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing code try changing to this,

```
var videos = $('.videolink').length;
$ (".scrollbox").width(
    ( $(".ytimg").width() + $('.videotext').width() ) * videos
);
```

You were missing quotes at `$(.videotext)`, also `$` was at wrong place `$ ( (".ytimg")` and missing at `(.videotext)`.